# Connection problem between Visual Basic .NET and Access Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I am having an issue here. there is a connection problem between Visual Basic .NET and Access Database.

In the first scenario, the access file type that i was using was **.accdb**. When I was trying to link the connection between Access and .Net, there is a message box showing that I did not install the Access engine (**But I DID**). fyi, I installed the x64 version.

In the second scenario, the access file type that i was using was **.mdb**. However, in this attempt, the connection was success.

So... can someone briefly explain this, is this a common problem with my computer or did I installed the wrong version of access engine? Your help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you using OLE-DB or ODBC? I recommend sticking to only the 32-bit ODBC driver (and compiling your VB.NET program to a 32-bit executable).

Comment: Also, please post your full connection-string. Note that the file-format version of the Access database (e.g. 97, 2002, 2003, 2007+) is important as the ACE and JET Red drivers are not cross-compatible across all file versions and host ISAs (honestly, the state of the MS Access ecosystem is in a mess right now - and Access hasn't received any real updates since 2003 and its SQL engine hasn't been changed since 1997... smh Microsoft)

Comment: `Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Login
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=oceana.mdb"
        con.Open()
    End Sub`

Comment: @Dai, hi, i am using .Jet. since the access file type is .mdb

Comment: You can read `.mdb` files using the ACE OleDb provider (12 or 16) without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jet is only available in 32-bit format so, if that worked, your application must be 32-bit. That would explain why the 64-bit version of ACE did not work for the ACCDB file. That means that, to use ACE, you either need the 32-bit version installed or your app needs be 64-bit.

It is generally recommended that you install 32-bit ACE unless you specifically need 64-bit. That's because Office is generally 32-bit (that's what Microsoft recommend, although 64-bit is available if you need the specific advantages) and VS apps are 32-bit (Any CPU, Prefer 32-bit) by default.

If your project targets the x86 platform then it will always be 32-bit and won't run on systems that don't support 32-bit. If your project targets the x64 platform then it will always be 64-bit and won't run on systems that don't support 64-bit. If your project targets *Any CPU* and *Prefer 32-bit* is checked then it will be 32-bit if it can, otherwise it will be 64-bit. If your project targets *Any CPU* and *Prefer 32-bit* is NOT checked then it will be 64-bit if it can, otherwise it will be 32-bit.

EDIT:

For those who don't understand this, assuming that you're on 64-bit Windows for Intel/AMD, try the following:

1. Create a new VB Console Application project.
2. Add the following code:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(If(Environment.Is64BitProcess, "64-bit", "32-bit"))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

3. Open Compile page of the project properties.
4. Set the *Target CPU* to *x86* and run the project.
5. Set the *Target CPU* to *Any CPU*, check the *Prefer 32-bit* box and run the project.
6. Set the *Target CPU* to *Any CPU*, UNcheck the *Prefer 32-bit* box and run the project.
7. Set the *Target CPU* to *x64* and run the project.

You will see that the first two cases display "32-bit" and the last two cases display "64-bit", exactly as I explained above.

Note that the `Is64BitProcess` property requires at least .NET Framework 4.0 or .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: OIC, my visual studio application is automatically saved in the Program Files (x86) in the installation process, so it should make sense that my application is 32 bit, thanks for helping.

Comment: if you set your project  to "any cpu" it will run as x32. This is because Visual Studio is x32, and thus during a debug session, or f5 to to run, you get a x32 bit version. So, if you going test or debug  and you want x64 bits? Then you have to force  the .net project to x64 bits, and it will thus run + launch as x64 bits. This also explains why the mdb file works, since all versions of windows have the x32 bit version installed by default. But for accdb files you have to install ACE.  And since you REALLY did install x64 bit ACE? Then you have to set + run your .net app as x64 to work fine.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, that's not true. Firstly, there's no such thing as x32. There's x86 and 32-bit. Secondly, the fact that VS is 32-bit is irrelevant. Thirdly, targeting *Any CPU* does not mean the program will run in a 32-bit process. If you read my answer then you'll see what it actually means. *Any CPU* means it can run 32-bit or 64-bit but the preferred mode is specified by the *Prefer 32-bit* check box. You seem to be trying to repeat my answer but getting it wrong. If you have questions about the question, comment on the question.

Comment: Context dude - EVERYTHING is context!  Yes, the x86 "process" is for 20+ years means an x32 bit process (end of that debate!!!).What I was saying is that FROM VS ANY CPU will always produce x32 bit process. If you launch your application outside of VS, then as you state ANY CPU can take on the “in-process” bit size automatic. What this means is that if you going to test with x64 then you can’t use ANY in VS for that testing. You would thus in theory change it back to ANY CPU right before deployment. and no there is not x86 and 32 bit (type-o on your part). we have ANY, x64, x86 as choices

Comment: Firstly, again, there's no such thing as x32. There's the x86 platform and there's 32-bit. x32 bit is not a thing. Secondly, this is utterly false: *"What I was saying is that FROM VS ANY CPU will always produce x32 bit process"*. Read the edit to my answer and follow the instructions to see for yourself.

Comment: Yes, you can un-check the prefer x32 - you have to be using .net 4.5 or later. So yes, you can force the issue. If you don't force the issue, or you are pre .net 4.5, then ANY CPU will and did produce a x32 bit in-line process.  Connection builders inside of VS will fail to x64 ACE but NOT when you run the project as x64. In this context, x32 is a thing. They do NOT and have NEVER called the windows x32 bit api as x86 windows api!!! And they don't call x32 bit running processes as x86 processes!!! A x32 bit process has been 100% consistent use for 30+ years.

Comment: So to be clear: Yes, ANY cpu can be forced to x64 now with 4.5 or later, but it not by default and not been that way for 20 years

Comment: I am not wrong. I stated that choosing ANY CPU will NOT get you a x64 bit process. And it DOES NOT. If you want to expand the steps you take to make this happen then no problem here. Choosing ANY CPU does not and will NOT result in an x64 bit process. Of course ANY CPU and you launch the x64 bit command line and then launch the .exe it will run as x64. A half dozen ways extra steps to Sunday CAN GET x64 bit process, but it is a CLEAR FACT that JUST choosing ANY CPU will result in an x32 bit process from VS. If you want to introduce extra hoops to make your point then then. My point stands.